# chrome debugger promises dont resolve while paused?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Maybe I'm not debugging promises right but basically if you stop at break point and run async code it doesnt actually finishes until you resume execution and that's a problem. Debugger allows you to quickly experiment with multiple api methods... but you cant if you resume it

```
debugger;
//now type the following in console
Promise.resolve().then(()=> console.log('done'));
```

Answer (score 4):

A possible workaround for this is to put `debugger` in your `.then` callback as well. This won't work in all situations but it worked for my particular case of debugging node.js scripts before they exit:

1. insert this into the JS code that you want to debug

   ```
   debugger;
   ```
2. when the debugger stops, type the following at the console prompt:

   ```
   expressionReturningPromise().then( r => {
     console.log('done');
     debugger;
   });
   ```
3. resume script execution

The dev tools will then pause on the debugger within the `.then` callback and you'll have the resolved value of your promise available for examination.

Comment: Clever workaround. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't execute because the function in `.then` is only called when the current "thread" is finished. This is the same for all asynchronous calls such as `setTimeout`.

Comment: yes, so that can be fixed. or is there another way to debug promises based methods

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Methods of debugging promises is another problem. My answer simply points out that the callback in `.then` will not be execute until the current block of code ("thread") is finished.

Comment: If you're using Chrome / Chromium, you won't be able to run await in the DevTools console due to this issue : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=833928

Comment: `console.log(3);
await (new Promise((r,x)=> setTimeout(function(){console.log(4); r(); }, 2000)))
console.log(5);`