# How to run asynchronous code in chrome devtools when script execution is paused?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

`await Promise.resolve(1)` in chrome devtools (chrome version 70.0.3538.77) resolves to:

- `1` when script execution is not paused
- `Promise <pending>` when script execution is paused

How to resolve it to `1` when script execution is paused

[image]

N.B.

this question continues [chrome debugger promises dont resolve while paused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47216353/chrome-debugger-promises-dont-resolve-while-paused) to find the exact way to resolve promises when chrome is paused

Comment: `console.log(await Promise.resolve(1))`

Comment: @Keith, no, it resolves to `Promise <pending>` too

Comment: @Keith, here is the reproduction https://imgur.com/a/oDDDet9

Comment: No it resolves to 1, what your seeing in the console is the promise been returned, not it's resolved value,.. If and when you un-pause the debugger, you will see the value `1` in the console output.  You can't get 1 while paused, that's impossible, because it hasn't yet happened.

Comment: Aren't you basically asking how to continue executing a script, while script execution is paused?

Comment: @Keith you didnt mention that I should unpause execution, this doesnt work for me

Comment: @DanielBeck I dont want to execute the script, I want to execute async functions while script is paused (think about it, I can calculate ordinary functions while paused, but not async calls, why?)

Comment: `yes, exactly `  In Chrome under Sources, on the right hand side are your `pause / run / step over` debugging tools,. I think that's what your looking for.

Comment: @Keith, no, this doesnt work for me (I have modified my comment above)

Comment: `but not async calls, why?`,  async calls run in the next tick, because you have paused there is never a next tick,.  sync calls inside the console of course don't require a next tick.

Comment: @Keith so, it's impossible?

Comment: Yes,. JS is single threaded, this means it has 1 single message loop.  When you pause, it will pause the message loop.  If it didn't it would make debugging even harder.  What problem are you trying to solve, I wonder if this is an X/Y problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185492/discussion-between-srghma-and-keith).

Answer (score 2):

Answer - it's not possible to make promises resolve WHEN js is paused in chrome, even promises that are created in console

(js is single threaded)